# Mongo finding items through subobject

Tags: mongodb

Mongo finding items through sub-object

```
 { "_id" : ObjectId("4f93aaddaca610f76b000000"),
   "count" : NumberLong(2),
   "items" : [
            {"count" : NumberLong(1),
             "options":{ "1":"track","2" : "track" } },

            {"count":NumberLong(2),
             "options":{"1":"as","2" : "sadf" } }
             ]
 }
```

How to sort the things in the sub-objects like limit the items list per request

result i expect is this

```
 { "_id" : ObjectId("4f93aaddaca610f76b000000"),
   "count" : NumberLong(2),
   "items" : [
            {"count" : NumberLong(1),
             "options":{ "1":"track","2" : "track" } },
             ]
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that. Querying embedded arrays is pretty limited now. Some day we'll have [virtual collections (SERVER-142)](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-142) and we'll be able to do sort , skip, limit and all other usual things. But right now we have these options:

- Fetch whole subarray and process it in the application;
- Move items to their own collection (reference instead of embedding);
- Use [Aggregation Framework](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework) (not yet released);
- Give up the idea.

Comment: Could we write a javascript to narrow it down

Comment: You don't wanna do that. Javascript is slow and single-threaded.

Comment: Even couchdb lacks this feature ?

Comment: I don't know couch well enough.

Comment: You mentioned about referencing, its like create a new item and reference it to the main. or i am i missing any feature in Mongodb

Comment: [Embed vs Link](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design#SchemaDesign-EmbeddingandLinking)

Comment: Referencing is the same as foreign key constraint in SQL.
belongs-to relationships.

Comment: @toninoj, no, it's not a constraint.

Comment: It's not a constraint, but it is parallel to foreign keys in SQL.
One field references a document in other collection.
Mongodb is generally constraintless, schemaless, you can design it on the fly.
Obviously.